# How to get and set Local Variable List for a process in JBPM 6?

Tags: java, jbpm

Is there a way to get and set the global/local variable list through code in JBPM 6?

I saw the documentation for JBPM version 3 like below:

```
ProcessInstance processInstance = ...;
ContextInstance contextInstance = (ContextInstance) processInstance.getInstance(ContextInstance.class);
```

But this seems deprecated, and gives me an error.

Additionally, I can set the variables through the bpmn editor using

```
kcontext.setVariable("isApproved", false);
```

But I'm not quite sure how to do retrieve this `kcontext` variable in code. I went through the getter methods for both an `KieSession` object and a `ProcessInstance` object, but no luck.

**Update**:
I can access these local variables through the `params` map object which is passed to the `ksession.startProcess(...)` method. Is this the only way to get/set local/global variable lists?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider this example - https://developer.jboss.org/people/bpmn2user/blog/2011/02/21/jbpm5-example-for-forms-with-variables

here a map is being set in the kContext instead of individual values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I have been accessing my process variables

```
String variableName = "Your_Variable_Name_here";
KieSession ksession = runtime.getKieSession();
ProcessInstance pi = ksession.getProcessInstance(processInstanceId);
RuleFlowProcessInstance rfpi = (RuleFlowProcessInstance)pi;
Object variable = rfpi.getVariable(variableName);
```

You should then cast your variable into the proper class.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Your solution works well for my case. I just have one question. Is the way that the `rfpi` object getting the variable through the `getVariable(variableName)` method same as the way that `kcontext.getVariable(variableName)` is getting the variable?

Comment: And additionally, is this way a good jBPM practice to get and set local variables from the perspective of jBPM 6 development?

Comment: So since I posted this it looks like JBPM 6.2 was officially released. If you use the org.jbpm.services.api.ProcessService has the following methods: void setProcessVariable(Long processInstanceId, String variableId, Object value) and Object getProcessInstanceVariable(Long processInstanceId, String variableName). If you are using CDI this can be injected directly into you container manager class via the following annotation: @Inject ProcessService processService;

Comment: Thanks Mike. Do you know whether these variables are persistent when the jBOSS server is restarted? (ie: can they be retrieved through some jBPM api so that the task can have the old values when the process is again running?)

Comment: jl987, my understanding is that by default the process variables are saved inside the database using the Serialization string; which is why all process variables needs to implement Serializable. I have not figured out how to retireve the values directly from the database. If you look at the variableinstancelog table, you can see the value and oldvalue columns; however, that only shows the toString values of the variables.

Answer (score 2):

See [this thread](https://developer.jboss.org/message/804237), you can access process instance variables executing this command in the KieSession:

```
Map<String, Object> variables = ksession.execute(new GenericCommand<Map<String, Object>>() {  

            public Map<String, Object> execute(Context context) {  
                StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = ((KnowledgeCommandContext) context).getStatefulKnowledgesession();  
                ProcessInstance processInstance = (ProcessInstance) ksession.getProcessInstance(piId);  
                VariableScopeInstance variableScope = (VariableScopeInstance) processInstance.getContextInstance(VariableScope.VARIABLE_SCOPE);  
                Map<String, Object> variables = variableScope.getVariables();  
                return variables;  
            }  
        });
```

If you just want to get one given process variable:

```
WorkflowProcessInstance p = (WorkflowProcessInstance)ksession.startProcess("the.process");
p.getVariable("the_process_variable")
```

To get all globals use `ksession.getGlobals()`.